# Getting timeout error while trying to get top 1 data with condition from database asynchronously

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get data on specific condition I want only the latest one data asynchronously using entuity framework , I have written query it works for specific ids and for others it is giving timeput error .

```
 await _context.Data
     .Where(m => m.Thumb== thumb)
     .OrderByDescending(m => m.ReceivedTime)
     .FirstAsync();
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the other columns?

Comment: How much data? What are the  `thumb` and `ReceivedTime` columns, are they indexed? The query itself says nothing. If `Thumb` and `ReceivedTime` aren't covered by any indexes, the server will have to scan and sort the entire table to retrieve the latest record

Comment: is there an index on `Thumb`? or perhaps a spanning index on `Thumb` then `ReceivedTime` (and is that last one `asc` or `desc`)? what is the *clustered* index here? how many rows are there for the ones you're interested in? note: this kind of query can also be prone to "parameter sniffing" problems if the data is skewed (some thumbs have very low counts, some have very large); if this was *manual* SQL you could largely mitigate that by using "option unknown" (on the thumb parameter), but: I don't think you can do that via EF.

Comment: `Async` won't make a slow query run fast, nor does it avoid timeouts. It avoids blocking the application while that query runs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  No they are not indexed columns .

Comment: @MitaliPatil Without indexing you can't improve performance

Answer (score 2):

> No they are not indexed columns

So, fix that; any one of:

```sql
create nonclustered index NCI_Data_Thumb_ReceivedTime on [Data] (Thumb, ReceivedTime)
create nonclustered index NCI_Data_Thumb_ReceivedTime on [Data] (Thumb, ReceivedTime desc)
create nonclustered index NCI_Data_Thumb on [Data] (Thumb)
```

should help

(note: follow you own local naming conventions)